# Resetting the game JS

Tags: javascript

So I am finally making progress!

My only issue, is that when the user dies instead of going back to the beginning when it askes for the user to press enter, it just fails.

Any thoughts?

```
if (0 > nx || nx > grid.width-1  ||
            0 > ny || ny > grid.height-1 ||
            grid.get(nx, ny) === SNAKE
        ) {
            init();
            update();
            return startGameScreen();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3aoozxte/41/

Comment: The code you've added in your question isn't present in your JSFiddle demo.

Comment: It should be. Yeah I have attempted a few things, but for some reason even if I call drawStartScreen() it just makes the text larger but doesnt actually reset the game :(